# Update Qty field in table based on Update Query

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables Inventory & Bom_Release joined by a Part_Num field the Inventory table contains a QTY field, the BOM_Release also has a qty_per field.
I have an aggregate query that sums the qty_per if the part_num is listed more than once.
I then have a query that looks at the Inventory table and the Aggregate query for a report.
All of that is working fine.

In the report I have qty and an unbound balance field, with
=[Inventory_Qty]-([Bom_Release_Qty]*[Forms!Kit_Release!WO_QTY_TXT]). Again the report works fine.
What I am struggling with is I can not figure out how to make an update query to do the same calculation as the report and actually update the qty in the Inventory table.
Very rusty, first DB I've done in almost 15 years. And even back then I was not very familiar with VBA. (I last used Access 97, Working with 365 now).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't save that data. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: Thanks you, However, I do not keep any info about the products in the database. All BOM info is stored in Excel spreadsheets. when a kit is released. the goal was to upload the BOM into the BOM_Release table (The table is cleared before the import.) and it will just reduce the Inventory qty by the qty_used*wo_qty.. I just started here and they have ZERO inventory control and ZERO complete BOM's. I am trying to start with this, and see if I can build off this as I go and get more experience with access. This is the last step I have before I am able to use what I have made so far. Thanks

Comment: An UPDATE action SQL cannot involve an aggregate query. If you need to update multiple records, options are DSum() domain aggregate function in UPDATE action SQL object or VBA looping through recordset. If you just want to edit a single record with value from calculated textbox, simple example: `CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table SET field = " & Me.textboxname & " WHERE ID = " & Me!ID`. The real trick is figuring out what event to put code in, possible report Close event.

Comment: OK, probably not the most elegant way to do it, but it worked in my case. I created another query that creates a new table with the results from my previous query. I am then able to run an update query from table to table. Again, probably not the best way to do it, But it is working.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that third approach. However, instead repeatedly creating table, table can be permanent and records are deleted and inserted each time process is run.

Comment: Yes, That is exactly what I did. Thanks Again.